Should custom SwiftUI views always conform to `View` protocol? Rather than subclassing an existing view type?
Building some basic views with SwiftUI, I come across situations where I want to build a TabView or some other built-in SwiftUI view type.
The general way to do this seems to be to create a new empty struct adopting the View protocol, which implements a var body: some View to build the view:
struct NavTabView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("Calendar")
                .tabItem { Label("Calendar", systemImage: "calendar.day.timeline.right") }
            Text("Chart")
                .tabItem { Label("Chart", systemImage: "chart.xyaxis.line") }
        }
    }
}

Coming from a more UIKit background, I perhaps feel like I want to instead inherit from the TabView view and use the superclass to build the view directly rather than pulling the TabView into my otherwise empty View + body. (If that makes sense.)
struct NavTabViewSubclass: TabView {
    // ERROR: Reference to generic type 'TabView' requires arguments in <...>
}

Should SwiftUI views always be a non-inheriting struct that conform to the View protocol?
Are there any cases where you would instead want to build a view by subclassing a concrete SwiftUI view as shown above? Is that even possible?

You can’t subclass a struct in Swift.

@HangarRash Hah, that's true. Did not consider that in the context of SwiftUI. Error also mentions nothing about it, as it does for non-SwiftUI code.

worth learning the basics of Swift structs before beginning SwiftUI
